# SimpleDateFormat is not displaying date properly

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am having some dates to display in Android app which come from a specific format from database. I am currently using `SimpleDateFormat` to display the date properly but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
          {
              "activity_date": "15/02/2016",
              "activity_game_name": "",
              "activity_title": "Played Buble",
              "activity_type": 1,
              "activity_amount": 0
          },
          {
              "activity_date": "13/02/2016",
              "activity_game_name": "",
              "activity_title": "Win Jackpot",
              "activity_type": 2,
              "activity_amount": 532195
          }
```

And they display like:

[image]

and

[image]

which is not even close to the date i have and I cannot even say why it displays the wrong date.

My code:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = String.valueOf(formatter.format(new Date(activitiesHistory.get(position).getDate())));
holder.history_date.setText(formattedDate);
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: you're passing dd/mm/yyyy `new Date()` accepts mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: so what should i use to format the date?

Comment: You're formatting the date in the right way, you CREATE the date in the wrong way

Comment: so how should i create it? is there a constructor that is accepting dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: There's a `Date(int year, int month, int day)` but it's deprecated. Use `Calendar` to create date, set month, year and day with `set(int year, int month, int date)`, and extract it with `getTime()`.
Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change YYYY to yyyy.

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: still the year is not displaying properly

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Please notice used imports.

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = formatter.format(activitiesHistory.get(position).getDate());
holder.history_date.setText(formattedDate);
```

You have bug in your string pattern - `MMM` instead of `MM`. 
Besides, using `String.valueOf(...)` and `new Date(...)` in 2nd line is pointless.